# How to add parameters in PreparedStatement in Postgresql JDBC without manually setting the types

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Is this possible?  We're using a PreparedStatementSetter, and the code is littered with statements like `preparedStatement.setString(4,"string");`

We have a lot of columns, so this is unfortunate.  It seems like it ought to be possible via the various metadata JDBC methods, and therefore I assume it has already been done (only half-joking).

We're on Spring 3.0 and PGJDBC 9.1-903

Comment: DAO classes possible/acceptable? JdbcTemplate?

Comment: Yeah, basically just JdbcTemplate, although I could probably shoehorn in SimpleJdbcTemplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`PreparedStatement#setObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) and let the JDBC driver identify the type of the parameter by itself.

For example, doing

```
preparedStatement.setObject(4,"string");
```

Will execute, in the end

```
preparedStatement.setString(4,"string");
```

You can even create a method to insert the parameters for you. Here's a basic example:

```
public void addParameters(PreparedStatement pstmt, Object ... parameters)
    throws SQLException {
    int paramIndex = 1;
    for (Object param : parameters) {
        pstmt.setObject(paramIndex++, param);
    }
}
```

And just set the parameters by:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = ...
addParameters(preparedStatement, 1, "string", new java.util.Date());
```

Comment: And the overhead for setObject as opposed to setSomeNativeType is paid only once, in the statement creation - is that correct?

Comment: @alex I've never suffered for an *overhead* in my apps using this approach. If you have a bottleneck, use a profiler to spot it instead of suppose where the problem may lie.